# Nepali language strings not supporting for Android

Tags: android

I want to integrate the Nepali language for one of my Android application.

Am using Preeti.ttf file in my assets, but it's not supporting

When I copying the strings from the doc, it's showing unsupported string like below

Am worked with Arabic language it's supporting well, but Nepali not supporting

Kindly help me to integrate the Nepali language.

Ex. Nepali strings (contents)
k|jw{g

cgÚs'n  ठाउँहरू छोड्नुहोस्

लोकप्रिय ठाउँहरू छोड्नुहोस्

क्षमता

kÚÚUg]  :yfg

lng"kg]{  ठाउँ सच्याउनका लाप्रि प्रिच्नु होस्

प्रलने स्िान छान्न नक्शा प्रमलाउनु होस्

तपाईंको प्रलने स्िान पुप्रि िनुुहोस्

lng"kg{]  पुप्रि िनुुहोस्

;lqmo  ePsf]  cgÚs'n  ljsNk  %f]*\g]

lgliqmo  ePsf]  cgÚs'n  ljsNk  %f]*\g]

cgÚs'n  ठाउँहरू छोड्नुहोस्

kÚÚUg  स्िान छोड्नुहोस्

तपाईको फोनको समय प्रमलाउनु र फे री ियास िनुु होला

kv{g]  ef*f  k|lt  #G^f

cgÚs'n  rfns  ljsNk  ;lqmo  ul/Psf]%

cgÚs'n  rfns  ljsNk  lgliqmo  ul/Psf]%

Comment: Welcom to SO. Please take a look at [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) It is unclear what exactly you are expecting from us right now

Comment: Please provide some codes and/or Stack trace if present.

Comment: I have edited my question, please take a look and update. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try SakalBharati.ttf font for Nepali language hope this will support.

Here is the link to download -

[Sakal Bharti](http://tdil-dc.in/index.php?lang=en)

PS - You might need multiple fonts to support different language correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But When I copying the strings from the doc & pasting into String.xml, it's showing unsupported string like mentioned kÚÚUg स्िान छोड्नुहोस्

Comment: oh I also faced this issue with word file, thats the problem with word file, some times word file contain hidden character's while copy and pasting better try to paste in notepad in utf-8 and from there copy and paste in string.xml. hope this will help.